# rewrite not a member of LiftRules

Tags: java, scala, lift

I was following http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/liftweb/URL_Rewriting tutorial for url rewritting in liftweb.. but I get this error:

```
error: value rewrite is not a member of object net.liftweb.http.LiftRules
```

.. it is really odd.. and the documentation says that it exists.

I'm using idea IDE, and I've done everything from scratch, using the lift maven blank archifact.

Some more info:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Joseph3
[INFO]    task-segment: [tomcat:run]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Preparing tomcat:run
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] [yuicompressor:compress {execution: default}]
[INFO] nb warnings: 0, nb errors: 0
[INFO] artifact org.mortbay.jetty:jetty: checking for updates from scala-tools.org
[INFO] artifact org.mortbay.jetty:jetty: checking for updates from central
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [scala:compile {execution: default}]
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[INFO] /home/dpz/Scala/Doit/Joseph3/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling

[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /home/dpz/Scala/Doit/Joseph3/target/classes at 1274922123910
[ERROR] /home/dpz/Scala/Doit/Joseph3/src/main/scala/bootstrap/liftweb/Boot.scala:16: error: value rewrite is not a member of object net.liftweb.http.LiftRules
[INFO]     LiftRules.rewrite.prepend(NamedPF("ProductExampleRewrite") {
[INFO]               ^
[ERROR] one error found
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] wrap: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1(Exit value: 1)

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 27 03:02:07 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/175M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 1

enter code here
```

Comment: What version of Lift are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Please user Lift 2.0-RC1.  The wiki article is based on Lift 2.0.